# Can One Firebase App(One google_services.json) used in Two Android App of different package name

Tags: android, firebase

Is it possible to use two android app with different package like com.base.free and com.base.paid using One Firebase App by creating a common json config file with common package like com.base.*  ????

Please suggest any way if possible.
Any help would be highly appreciable and Voted.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to create a project in firebase console and add the two apps to the same project. You can download the same google.services.json for two different android projects then.

- Add Project
- Project Name

After creating project you'll be provided with option to add app
*Create Project

Open **Project Overview** and click on **Add App**

Use the package names as desired for each project. The google-services.json can be used and will work for both apps.

Answer (score 0):

One Google_services.json file, No.
One Google Project or Firebase Project and two apps, yes.

The google_services.json file contains a few app specific settings that can't be used across other apps.